Is every infinitely dimensional complex Banach space the complexification of a real Banach space?
If we have a real Banach space, we can always complexify it into a complex Banach space.

But for an infinitely dimensional complex Banach space $X$, does it always exist a real closed subspace $V$, such that $X$ is the complexification of $V$?

Since every complex space is also a real space, it seems this question should be split into two parts:

When is a real Banach space also a complex one?


If $X$ is such a real Banach space, when does it admit a complemented subspace $V$ s.t. $X=V\oplus_\mathbb{R} V$?

Thanks in advance.

Look for indecomposable Banach spaces.

@Jochen Thanks. Are there specific books covering this topic?

Another idea: any complexification of a real Banach space admits an anti-linear automorphism, namely sending $x + iy$ to $x - iy$. In other words, any such space is isomorphic to its complex conjugate. Is there a Banach space that is not isomorphic to its complex conjugate? That would then be a counterexample.

@DavidGao, yes such spaces to exist: https://kaltonmemorial.missouri.edu/assets/docs/cmb1995.pdf

@TomaszKania Ah, thanks! I assumed that would be the case, but I don't really know much about general Banach spaces. I suppose that answers the OP's question, then. Do you want to write an answer?

@TomaszKania Thanks a lot for the link
